# How to add full-screen overlay ad when transitioning pages on a website?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Sometimes, on a website, when I click a link, I get the full page blurred with what seems like a Google ad overlaid in the center, like this:

[image]

You have to click the blurred overlay to close the ad.

How do you add such functionality to your website? I am building a Next.js app and have integrated Google Adsense ads already, but I didn't see this as an option. What do I need to do to enable this sort of feature?

- What platform offers it (is it Google Ads)?
- How do I enable it on a single-page app on page transition essentially (at a high level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's called a Vignette ad. It can be enabled under Auto Ads, as [explained here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9305577?hl=en).

On your adsense account, go to Ads from the left sidebar, then on the ad you want to display Vignette ads on, turn auto ads on.